# Replace automatic text color to some explicit color in selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to write a macro, which finds all blocks of text with `Font.ColorIndex = wdColorAutomatic` and changes it to wdColorWhite?

I need it to paste rich text to a panel with black background in Confluence wiki. Default colour for this background is grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub Test()
      With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .Text = "wdColorAutomatic"
      .Replacement.Text = "wdColorWhite"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```